# How to encode nested Python Protobuf

Tags: java, python, websocket, protocol-buffers

Been stumped on this for a while and pulling what is left of my hair out.

Sending non-nested Protobufs from Python to Java and Java to Python without
an issue with WebSockets. My problem is sending a nested version over a WebSocket. I believe my issue is on
the Python encoding side.

Your guidance is appreciated.

.proto file

```
message Response {
  // Reflect back to caller
  required string service_name = 1;

  // Reflect back to caller
  required string method_name = 2;

  // Who is responding
  required string client_id = 3;

  // Status Code
  required StatusCd status_cd = 4;

  // RPC response proto
  optional bytes response_proto = 5;

  // Was callback invoked
  optional bool callback = 6 [default = false];

  // Error, if any
  optional string error = 7;
  //optional string response_desc = 6;
}

message HeartbeatResult {
    required string service = 1;
    required string timestamp = 2;
    required float status_cd = 3;
    required string status_summary = 4;
}
```

A Heartbeat result is supposed to get sent in the reponse_proto field
of the Response Protobuf. I am able to do this in Java to Java but Python
to Java is not working.

I've included two variations of the python code. Neither of which works.

```py
   def GetHeartbeat(self):
    print "GetHeartbeat called"
    import time
    ts = time.time()
    import datetime
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    heartbeatResult = rpc_pb2.HeartbeatResult()
    heartbeatResult.service = "ALERT_SERVICE"
    heartbeatResult.timestamp = st
    heartbeatResult.status_cd = rpc_pb2.OK
    heartbeatResult.status_summary = "OK"

    response = rpc_pb2.Response()
    response.service_name = ""
    response.method_name = "SendHeartbeatResult"
    response.client_id = "ALERT_SERVICE"
    response.status_cd = rpc_pb2.OK 
    response.response_proto = str(heartbeatResult).encode('utf-8')

    self.sendMessage(response.SerializeToString())
    print "GetHeartbeat finished"

   def GetHeartbeat2(self):
    print "GetHeartbeat called"
    import time
    ts = time.time()
    import datetime
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    heartbeatResult = rpc_pb2.HeartbeatResult()
    heartbeatResult.service = "ALERT_SERVICE"
    heartbeatResult.timestamp = st
    heartbeatResult.status_cd = rpc_pb2.OK
    heartbeatResult.status_summary = "OK"

    response = rpc_pb2.Response()
    response.service_name = ""
    response.method_name = "SendHeartbeatResult"
    response.client_id = "ALERT_SERVICE"
    response.status_cd = rpc_pb2.OK 
    response.response_proto = heartbeatResult.SerializeToString()
    self.sendMessage(response.SerializeToString())
    print "GetHeartbeat finished"
```

Errors on the Java server side are:

```
(GetHeartbeat) Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag
and
(GetHeartbeat2)
Message: [org.java_websocket.exceptions.InvalidDataException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.java_websocket.util.Charsetfunctions.stringUtf8(Charsetfunctions.java:80)
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.deliverMessage(WebSocketImpl.java:561)
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decodeFrames(WebSocketImpl.java:328)
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decode(WebSocketImpl.java:149)
    at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer$WebSocketWorker.run(WebSocketServer.java:593)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:277)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:798)
    at org.java_websocket.util.Charsetfunctions.stringUtf8(Charsetfunctions.java:77)
```

Comment: Why is the status code a float? And do you need to define `rpc_pb2.OK` somewhere?

Comment: You have a good eye. I feared the post was already long so I left out the rpc_pb2.OK Here it is enum StatusCd {
  // Server-side errors
  OK = 1;
  ...
} Also you are correct the status code should not be a float...an error for sure.

Comment: Are you sure the client and the server are using compatible .proto files? Maybe the field types are different or something.

Comment: Double checked .proto files and recompiled Python just now to be sure. Same response. The non-nested is working without issue. I'm guessing the SerializeToString on the inner and then again on the entire message probably is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Also posted this question on protobuf group

Credit to Christopher Head and Ilia Mirkin for providing input on the google group

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/Cp7zWiWok9I

```
response.response_proto = base64.b64encode(heartbeatResult.SerializeToString())
self.sendMessage(response.SerializeToString())
```

FYI, Ilia also suggested base64 encoding the entire message but this seems to be working at the moment.